have Discord.js bot support both slash commands and prefix
is there any way that i can get my bot to support both discords slash commands and my bot prefix without any headache
right now my bot works with the prefix ; or whatever prefix is set in the guild, my command handler is
    const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, "commands");

    try {
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);
        client.commands = new Map();
    
        // Loop through command folders and files to populate client.commands
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
            try {
                const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
                
                for (const file of commandFiles) {
                    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
                    
                    try {
                        const command = require(filePath);
                        // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
                        if ("data" in command && "execute" in command) {
                            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                            // Add aliases to the command collection
                            if (command.data.aliases && Array.isArray(command.data.aliases)) {
                                command.data.aliases.forEach((alias) => {
                                    client.commands.set(alias, command);
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(`[ERROR] Failed to load command from file: ${filePath}`, err);
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`[ERROR] Failed to read commands in folder: ${commandsPath}`, err);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`[ERROR] Failed to read command folders from: ${foldersPath}`, err);
    }

really messy and trashy, but it works,im wondering if i can edit it in some way to make every command have slash command support too

There is no shortcut to convert message commands directly into slash commands. The only way to do this is to create your own algorithms.
Things to consider when creating your algorithm:

When integrating your prefix commands into the slash commands, you must also transfer the options that the message command receives to the slash. You need to record information such as whether the options are required and what type they are (role, user, string, number, etc.) in the data of each of your message commands.

Also, do not forget to transfer the permissions you set in your prefixed commands to the slash commands.


Along with this, if you build your message commands as follows, it will be easier to do what I said.
const command = {
 name: "kick",
 permissions: PermissionsBitField.Flags.KickMembers,
 options: [
  { name: "user", "type": "user", isRequired: true },
  { name: "reason", "type": "string", isRequired: false }
 ],
 execute: (message) => {
  // Your code
 }
}

export default command

If you don't want to deal with these, you can browse templates on Github and clone repos with the features you want.
A recent sample template: https://github.com/labcord/Ruvia
